# filter using dplyr AND statement

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am working with coordinates, and I need to remove `(0,0)` coordinate from a dataset,
I am using `filter()` and `&` statements to do that

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,0,0,0), y=c(0,1,0,1,0))
df |> filter(x !=0 & y !=0)
>  x y
> 1 1 1
```

However, when I use `filter(x !=0 & y !=0)` it does what `filter(x !=0 , y !=0)` does, removes points where x `OR` y is 0 , not x `AND` y is 0.

Am I using wrong syntax?

Comment: Use `|` insteed of `&` i.e. `df |> filter(x !=0 | y !=0)`

Comment: thank you! i guess i misinterpreted the & symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @akrun, the syntax should be `|` not `&`

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,0,0,0), y=c(0,1,0,1,0))
df |> filter(x !=0 | y !=0)
```